# Can the audio stream output from the earpiece during a call be captured?

Tags: android

I am looking to develop an application and would like to know if the earpiece audio output can be captured.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [`MediaRecorder.AudioSource`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html) I would say that this should be possible using the [`VOICE_DOWNLINK` source](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_DOWNLINK).

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK);
```